# recently,the sybase database report some errors,I don't know how to solve,

Tags: sql, sap-ase

Recently I used the sybase database and it report some errors, I searched many information and Expand configuration, but it's still happening.

My server computer memory and the cpu usage is normal, I don't know if machines system resources are enough for it.

This is Part of my sybase error log:

```
02:00000:00000:2011/12/31 10:13:21.60 kernel  nl__read_defer: read failed on socket 36.

02:00000:00000:2011/12/31 10:13:25.92 kernel  nl__read_defer: read failed on socket 154.
system resources not enough,Can not complete the requested service
06:00000:00000:2011/12/31 10:13:32.70 kernel  nl__read_defer: read failed on socket 164.
system resources not enough,Can not complete the requested service
00:00000:00000:2011/12/31 10:13:34.40 kernel  nl__read_defer: read failed on socket 34.
system resources not enough,Can not complete the requested service
....more

00:00000:00014:2012/01/04 10:25:03.59 kernel  NT operating system error 1450 in module 'e:\ase1253\porttree\svr\sql\generic\ksource\strmio\n_winsock.c' at line 1987

00:00000:00014:2012/01/04 10:25:03.59 kernel  NT operating system error 1450 in module 'e:\ase1253\porttree\svr\sql\generic\ksource\strmio\n_winsock.c' at line 1987
....more

 ct_results(): network packet layer: internal net library error: Net-Library operation terminated due to disconnect.
```

my sybase product is ASE,and my machine memory is 4G
there are some configuration about sybase which I changed:

```
[Named Cache:default data cache]
    cache size = 1400M
[Meta-Data Caches]
    number of open databases = 50
    number of open objects = 5000
    number of open indexes = 5000
[Disk I/O]
    number of devices = 20
[Physical Memory]
    max memory = 2000000
[Processors]
    max online engines = 8
    number of engines at startup = 8
[SQL Server Administration]
    procedure cache size = 400000
[User Environment]
    number of user connections = 200
[Lock Manager]
   number of locks = 150000
[Rep Agent Thread Administration]
   enable rep agent threads = 1
```

the other configuration are Default

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what Sybase Product are you using? (for example, ASE or IQ). And what are your machine resources?